# How to create a ' character constant

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, char, switch-statement, special-characters

I am writing a program that needs to check input for anything including the ' character, which is what I am having a problem with:

```
case ''':
   //some code
   break;
```

Gives me these errors:

```
error C2137: empty character constant
error C2001: newline in constant
```

Is there a way to format it in a way that will allow me to write that case?
My only other idea is make it my default case, which isn't at all what I would like.

Comment: You have to use `'\''`

Comment: third page in every C (C++) handbook

Comment: @JacekCz - Just because the answer is simple, doesn't make this an unworthy question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special characters need to be escaped, in order to be used in that sense, like this:

```
case '\'':
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `'\''`, `'\x27'` or even **`*"'"`**. You can also cast an `int` with value `0x27` to a `char`, but this gets more unreadable like `'\x27'` already does.

C++ allows `*"'"` in switch and constexpr statements, but lazy compilers for C may apply runtime pointerarithmetic on it.

Comment: Hard-coding magic numbers is never a good idea. The C++ language definition does not require that single quote be represented by the value 0x27.

Comment: The C++ Standard (2014) requires `case *"'":` to work.

Comment: I do not think that old and c-compilers support it.

Comment: @aschepler and while we're here, `int _[*"'"];`

Comment: There is no good reason to use anything other than `'\''` unless you're writing deliberately obfuscated code.